# R not reading Rprofile.site at startup

Tags: linux, profile, gnu, r

When I start `R` it’s [meant](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html) to read from `/etc/Rprofile.site` first thing. I’ve verified that this isn’t happening but have no idea why or how to fix it. When I `source('/etc/Rprofile.site')` at startup everything goes fine.

---

Some random things I thought to investigate, which may be useful for someone who wants to help or may be irrelevant…

```
$ which R
/usr/bin/R

$ ls -l /usr/bin/R
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8589 … /usr/bin/R
```

(nothing fishy hiding in a pointer/softlink so that’s not it)

```
$ echo $R_HOME

$ less ~/.Renviron
/home/isomorphismes/.Renviron: No such file or directory

> Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
[1] "/usr/lib/R"

> Sys.getenv("RHOME")
[1] "~/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/"
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm seeing the same thing for R on RHEL 7

Comment: R wouldn't read the `.Rprofile` in my home directory. My solution was to go to `/usr/lib/R/etc` and create a softlink there: `sudo ln -sf ~/.Rprofile`. Not sure if this is the way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to see what R thinks its R_HOME (or RHOME) is. Try to run

```
R RHOME
```

that should print the value of RHOME and exit.

Alternatively, from the R command line

```
Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
```

I think R will read the startup and conf files  from `$(R RHOME)/etc/`

Maybe it's not the location you think it is...
Hope this helps

Regards

Comment: Thanks. `/usr/lib/R` for `R_HOME` and `~/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/` for `RHOME` … doesn't seem too bad?